# How to authenticate secured layer on Geoserver from javascript (leaflet/openlayers) requests

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, openlayers, apache, authentication

I have a Geoserver instance on a docker container that sits on an Ubuntu host. At the moment, requests to the Geoserver container are forwarded on through the host's Apache web server. I am making these requests from a javascript web application.

I would like to secure some of my layers on Geoserver.

**My question**: how can I provide the proper credentials (presumably, username and password) to access these layers from my javascript app without displaying them in plain view in my source code?

Comment: This is a generic programming question, that is better researched on SO

Comment: I think you're right. I posted their first, but then brought the question over here for visibility.  If it's unfit for gis.stackexchange feel free to close it.

Comment: @rumski20 do you have any update, or any thread that you've posted on other sites? and has the problem been solved?

Comment: @sutan we kind of abandoned the effort to secure access to Geoserver layers via authentication. Sorry to disappoint you here. I would still be interested in the answer. We've done some tightening up via host/IP matching in the Apache configuration.

Comment: I see, thanks, quite comforting. so basically, no authentication on the GeoServer for the layer is needed; but the layer is accessible if you are from a particular IP address? @rumski20